# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass in application_helper.rb method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling to get this application_helper method to work.  I am copying a few helper methods and pages from other open source code which is why it isn't working yet - I am converting some sinatra code to rails.  First here is the error I get:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the method

```
def current_link
root_path = "pages/"
current_route = request.path.sub(root_path, "").split("/") # pages/dashboard/stats.html -> ['dashboard', 'stats.html']
return current_route.first, current_route.last.split(".").first
end
```

The error is likely to do with root_path = "pages/" since this is a rails application.

My actually root path is technically:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

What should the actual method be?

Comment: Do a compact on current_route to remove nil values "current_route.compact.first, current_route.compact.split(".").first"

Comment: when you want to link to the current page, you can just use `url_for` without parameters